# Is there a modern alternative for using RDLC reports for printing and creating PDFs?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, rdlc, .net-5

In several applications .NET Framework applications, I'm currently using RDLC reports for printing documents or creating PDFs. This works fine, especially because of the designer in Visual Studio.

Now I'm upgrading some of these applications to .NET 5. I've searched online and see that there are some ways to still use RDLC reports in .NET 5, but they feel mostly like workarounds or are not up-to-date projects. Unless I missed something, of course.

What I'm looking for is an alternative for RDLC, preferably with a designer in Visual Studio. I've used some PDF libraries in the past (e.g. Spire.PDF), something like that could be a good solution, but is without a designer. Is there any another solution?

Comment: Tried [Crystal Report](https://www.sap.com/hk/products/crystal-visual-studio.html)? It's free as long as you are not selling the generated reports, it's good enough as ERP reporting solution.

Comment: Good suggestion, I've used it long ago, but didn't consider it for this. I have to check the license though